# Do I have to re-compile glibc 2.34 itself for full 64-bit time_t support for 32-bit hardware?

Tags: linux, time, arm, glibc, year2038

My CPU is of type `armhf`, so 32-bit. I run `Linux Kernel 5.4` on it (so it supports 64-bit time_t for 32-bit system). I compile programs against `glibc 2.34` (so time_t can be explicitely set to be 64-bit instead of 32-bit).

Now I am trying to get this simple piece of code working (test.c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int ret = 0;
    ret = lchmod ("/tmp/testme.file", 0755);
    printf("ret=%d; errno=%d, strerror=%s\n", ret, errno, strerror(errno));
    return 0;
}
```

(Cross-)Compile it like so:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_TIME_BITS=64 test.c -o test
```

To test the program I set my system date to 2084-01-01 (beyond year 2038 is important). Then I create a file by running `touch /tmp/testme.file`. This file gets a creation timestamp of 2084-01-01. Now when I run the above code `./test` it gives me this error message:

```
ret=-1; errno=75, strerror=Value too large for defined data type
```

It seems **Value too large for defined data type** error happens because the function `lchmod(...)` cannot handle files with creation timestamps beyond year 2038.

Why is this? Is this a glibc bug or does the `glibc 2.34` **itself** has to be re-compiled with additional CFLAGS `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_TIME_BITS=64`.

When I change `lchmod(...)` to `chmod(...)` it works.

Comment: `lchmod` ? Is `/tmp/testme.file` a symLink? `./test it gives me this error message:` What the value of `ret` and the value or `errno`?

Comment: @KamilCuk no it's not. BTW if I change `lchmod(...)` to `chmod(...)` it works. I tend to believe this is a glibc 2.34 bug.

Comment: This is overall odd - `lchmod` should fail with `ENOSYS`, it should not succeed, it's not available on Linux, and (99% of the time) you can't set permissions on symlinks, so it's pointless. Does compiling without any `-D_FILE...` macros makes `lchmod` suceeded? Please also add `errno = 0` before the call to `lchmod`. || Och, I see it was just implemented - https://sourceware.org/pipermail/glibc-cvs/2020q1/068786.html . Could you call `fchmodat (AT_FDCWD, "/tmp/testme.file", 0755 AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW);` And see if you have same error? Same error without `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW`?

Comment: I found several links where this might be related to -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 missing. As this I believe you have to recompile your libc. But if this is part of file system structure, you also need to update file system kernel things as well?

Comment: @KamilCuk `test.c` without `-D_FILE...` fails also when executed. Calling `fchmodat` with `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` set FAILS. Calling `fchmodat` **without** `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` set SUCCEEDS. Basically it behave like `lchmod` and `chmod`.

Comment: What filesystem are you running on? I _guess_ you are triggering this : https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/open.c#L1389 . That's the single EOVERFLOW I can see there :/

Comment: Is `__NR_lchmod` defined? https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fchmodat.c.html#34 Please _do not_ check on crosscompiler - check the target running linux system. Please also check if cross-compiler standard libraries are the same as on target.. is `arm-generic/errno.h` the same? Does the issue happen when _not_ crosscompiling? Please add `errno = 0` before callling `lchmod`. Either way, you _should_ end up in an error https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/77c1573dbceebf75203e4201615def9765599d87/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fchmodat.c#L35 , the suprising part is `errno=75`.

Comment: Or maybe `O_LARGEFILE` is missing in that open from here: https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/77c1573dbceebf75203e4201615def9765599d87/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fchmodat.c#L43 . If possible, would be great if you copy that code, add `O_LARGEFILE` to that open there and see if it works then. But even so, https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/77c1573dbceebf75203e4201615def9765599d87/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/fchmodat.c#L64 will fail with `EOPNOTSUPP`, so... Why are you using `lchmod` at all? It's just not supported on linux... And sure, I think you could post a bug to glibc - it should return ENOSYS

Comment: @KamilCuk in fact my demo program was just an excerpt from `coreutils`'s `mknod` source code (https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/mknod.c) At line 275 `lchmod` is called and fails. Also `mkfifo` uses `lchmod` and fails when permission parameter is set.

Comment: @arminb  Yes, I understand it runs on ARMHF.  It might have a micron memory chip as well.  However, the underlying problem seems to be with the software stack (this is not clear at this point, but it seems like a glibc bug).  Ie, if it is a glibc bug, it has nothing to do with the fact that you are running on ARMHF (nor Linux).  I don't fault you that it **COULD BE** arm related.  Just when you accept an answer, please remove the tag **IF** appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a glibc bug, you want a version that includes commit [118a2aee07f64d605b6668cbe195c1f44eac6be6](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=118a2aee07f64d605b6668cbe195c1f44eac6be6). That is v2.36 or newer.